# ember-data DS.RESTAdapter causes TypeError

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying out Ember.js with ember-data, and I have the following application defined:

```cs
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.store = DS.Store.create
    revision: 4
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create { bulkCommit: false }

App.Source = DS.Model.extend
    # options
    primaryKey: '_id'

    # fields
    name: DS.attr 'string'
    raw_text: DS.attr 'string'

App.sourcesController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create
    content: App.store.findAll App.Source

App.ListSourcesView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName: 'app/templates/sources/list'
    sourcesBinding: 'App.sourcesController'
```

That template looks like this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each sources}}
        {{view App.ShowSourceView sourceBinding="this"}}
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I try to load `App.ListSourcesView` in my page, I get an error in ember-data.js saying:   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and reading through the source isn't helping my confusion any in this case. Has anyone experienced this, or can tell me what I've defined/not defined incorrectly?

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle for your code and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/qySE9/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the same thing I ran into [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741443/85121). In short ember-data expects resource lists to be nested under the resource name, eg if you get /users/ then the result should be `{ "users": [] }` and not a top-level array `[]`.

Comment: I actually ended up using knockout. This is very likely it.

Comment: When serving data with rails, `active_model_serializers` is the good point to start from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ember/ember-data from github master? This is caused by an incompatibility in some versions over the past few months. Once I used master for both the error went away (along with lots of other bugs).

Comment: I wish it were so! I tried both from master and still got the error. I guess I'll just have to wait to use ember until ember-data matures a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
App.sourcesController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create
     content: []

App.ListSourcesView = Ember.View.extend
     // I don't believe you can use file paths in this way
     // Use a script tag with a  data-template-name as shown in the docs.
     // If you really need them from a file, then you will need to compile the templates
     // Yourself. There's plenty of SO Questions re: this.
     templateName: 'source-list'
     sourcesBinding: 'App.sourcesController'

// Always access ember object properties through the get and set interfaces.
// This will ensure that views get the proper notifications when props change.
App.sourcesController.set("content", App.store.findAll App.Source);
```

Let me know if this doesn't work out for you!