# Ember.js and ember-data error loading json

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I receive the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'map'
```

when using ember-data to try and load the json from my api.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Student = DS.Model.extend({
    primaryKey: 's_id',
    s_id: DS.attr('integer'),
    surname: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Student.reopenClass({
    url: 'api/student.php'
})

App.adapter = DS.Adapter.create({
    findAll: function(store, type) {
        var url = type.url;

        console.log(type.url);

        jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){
            store.loadMany(type, data);
        });
    }
});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 4,
    adapter: App.adapter
});

App.students = App.store.findAll(App.Student);
```

I've made sure the JSON is the correct format but to no avail; any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `data` should be an array -- is it not? Is it under a field like `data.results`? Can you show a sample response?

Comment: Here is the reponse:

`Object
student: Array[3]
0: Object
s_id: 1
surname: "Jones"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
s_id: 2
surname: "Smith"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
s_id: 3
surname: "Biggins"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object`

_sorry for the formatting issues_

Comment: Though the structure is lost, I get the impression `data.student` is the array of students you want to load into the store, not `data`. Is this correct?

Comment: You would think so, but the other answers to similar questions seemed to suggest that the root level of the JSON response had to be name the same as the instance of the student. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356129/ember-data-ds-restadapter-causes-typeerror?rq=1

Comment: See the comment above `store.loadMany` [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data#findmany) (but disregard `ids`, which isn't necessary with `findAll`). If that accepted answer is correct (which I don't believe it is), you probably want the array to be `data.students` not `data.student`

Comment: I think I know what's going on -- `DS.RestAdapter` does assume the pluralized form as the root of the json in [its implementation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L180) of `findAll`, but if you need this, you should either mimic this implementation or just use/extend that built-in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pauldechov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363073/pauldechov) answered this in a comment above:

> I think I know what's going on -- DS.RestAdapter does assume the
>   pluralized form as the root of the json in its implementation of
>   findAll, but if you need this, you should either mimic this
>   implementation or just use/extend that built-in one.

Because the root of the json is named, I can call data.student to get call loadMany correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I find it that when using a Custom Adapter it's best to define all methods (findAll, find, createRecord, createRecords, etc) in your App.adapter to avoid throwing errors.
You would think that implementing this methods step by step is best to control what's going on in your app, but the default adapter jumps in if you do it like this.

Also check for the correct formating of json response